# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency 'formdata'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Keep having a warning missing dependency in my form,
i tried input the formdata into the array of useEffect, but if i input the formdata, it will show Maximum update depth exceeded 
Full warning : "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency : 'formdata'. Either include it or remove the dependency array"
And my code is:

```
const [isRevealPassword, isRevealPasswordHandler] = useState(false);

const [formdata, formdataHandling] = useState({
    email: {
        value: '',
        config: {
            type: 'email'
        }
    },
    password: {
        value: '',
        config: {
            type: 'password'
        }
    }
});

useEffect(() => {
    const newFormdata = {
        ...formdata
    }
    const newElement = {
        ...newFormdata['password']
    }

    newElement.config.type = isRevealPassword ? 'text' : 'password';
    newFormdata['password'] = newElement;
    formdataHandling(newFormdata);
}, [isRevealPassword]) // <--- if I input formdata here, it will looping until Maximum update depth exceeded

const togglePassword = () => {
        isRevealPasswordHandler(!isRevealPassword);
    }



return (
    <span
        onClick={() => togglePassword()}
    >
        {
            isRevealPassword ? <FaEye /> : <FaEyeSlash />
        }
    </span>
)
```

the answer is in the comment below, all credits goes to mr @Yousaf ( will delete this message here, if mr Yousaf himself post the answer )

Comment: You could use functional form of the state updater function returned by the `useState` hook to get rid of `formData` as a dependency of the `useEffect` hook: `formdataHandling(prevFormData => { ... })`;

Comment: thank you for your reply @Yousaf, i still dont understand where do i put the formdataHandling(prevFormData => { ... }), do i put it inside the use effect? or i dont need the useeffect anymore? sorry for not understand.

Comment: do you mean like this :
useEffect(() => {
        
        formdataHandling(prevFormData => {
            const newFormdata = {
                ...prevFormData
            }
            const newElement = {
                ...newFormdata['password']
            }

           ...
        })
    }, [isRevealPassword])

if yes, its showing error "formdata is undefined"

Comment: oke please wait a minute

Comment: @Yousaf can i share the link in here?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-christian-01f67?file=/src/App.js

Comment: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wildflower-spkvb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Yousaf you solved it, thank you so much, could you post it as an answer, so i can choose your answer as a correct one.